# How to read the state of a checkbox in an excel file with EPPlus ( C# )

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

The title already explains my problem pretty well. I have an excel file which contains checkboxes and I would like to read their state (checked or not) using the EPPlus library.

[image]

I am not sure if this is even supported. So far I have found no documentation or examples for that specific problem using EPPlus.

Comment: Can I ask How did you managed to detect and  read checkbox from excel file?Thanks!

Comment: I didn't. It seems that it is not possible without a cell link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a Cell link then pulling the value is straight forward.  I don't believe that the Drawing Object contains the value.
[image: Checkbox Settings]

```
using System.Linq;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;

namespace EPPlus {
               public void Run() {
            var excelFile = new System.IO.FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(BaseDirectory, "Excel", "Checkbox.xlsx"));
            using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(excelFile))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Sheet1");
                ExcelDrawing checkbox2 = sheet.Drawings.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name == "Check Box 2");
               var value = sheet.Cells["G5"].Value.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am working with already existing Excel files and they have no Cell link. Until now I am still looking for a way to read the checkbox state when there is no Cell link.

Comment: @Niederee - wait what? How do you get "G5", programatically from checkbox2? I am fortunate enough that my spreadsheet author has included the cell link, but I don't see how to get it from the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

For existing excel, just designate a cell somewhere and link it to the checkbox. Insert the true/false value directly to that cell (NOT TO THE CHECKBOX). The checkbox will automatically reflect the value of the cell in the checkbox.

You can put all designated cells in a certain column, then hide that column. :)